# How to place button row and content left to image in bootstrap or css

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Product detail page should contain row with labels and buttons and table in right side of image.

Bootstap 3 is used and this page appears in bootstrap columns.
I tried

```
<div class="maincontent">

<!-- Image in left -->

    <div class="details-gallery hidden-xs">
        <a class="bigimg fbox">
            <img alt="" id="detail-mainimage" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class='inline-block'>

<!-- row with labels and buttons -->
<form>
<label for="spinner">
                quantity
            </label>
            <input id="spinner" class='amount '/>
             <label for='total_eur'>Sum</label>
            <span class='maincontent-paymentsum' id="total_eur"></span>
            <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn btn-success" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary " onclick="javascript: history.back(1)"
           value='Back' />
</form>
    </div>
   ...
   <!-- table which should be right to image -->
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-responsive inline-block">
```

but button row appears in bottom and table starts after it.

How to fix this so that content appears at right of image ?

How to put button row and table right to image like in first image in this question ?
This is Mono ASP.NET MVC3 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove `.inline-block` class from your code, and set `float:left` to `details-gallery hidden-xs` class. Then you'll need extra wrapper to contain whole right hand side of layout (`div.inline-block` `table.table-responsive` and `div.details-productdescription`) in one container ie. `div.product-info-wrapper`,
and `float` it to `left` too. You might also need to use `width: calc(100% - 270px);` on this element.

Let me know if it's unclear.

Comment: I implemented this without `float:left` and updated test url. Why float-left is required ? How to replace magic value `270px` with something more generic?

Comment: Your setup works, but if you hover over `div.product-info-wrapper` in chrome developer tools you'll see that without floating it, this element spans throughout entire width, which is incorrect. One correction you need to make, is to add calc() function not to the table, but to `div.product-info-wrapper` itself. `270px` is not a magic value here - but simply a width of your left hand side of layout, so to tell right hand side element, to fill rest of available space, you need to use `calc(100% - 270px)` function. Browser support for calc() function - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Comment: I moved calc to `.product-info-wrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 270px);
}` In this case table appears below of image like in picture in question. So this must be in table style

Comment: That's why you need `float:left` on `div.product-info-wrapper` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Apply "float:left" on image's div

```
   <div style="float:left" class="details-gallery hidden-xs">
    <a class="bigimg fbox">
        <img alt="" id="detail-mainimage" />
    </a>
   </div>
```

And reduce table's width :

```
<table style="width:350px" class="table table-hover table-condensed table-responsive inline-block">
```

that should do it